# How to upload and download audio files from Google Drive in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, google-drive-realtime-api

Is there any Google Drive API available for upload and download audio files in windows phone 7. If not then, is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google APIs Client Library for .NET](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/) doesn't support Windows Phone 7 [yet](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=114), but you can send raw HTTP requests from your app and implement the protocol yourself.

Check the Google Drive SDK documentation for [upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads) and [download](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads) instructions.